# Why is my shinyMobile PWA's manifest.webmanifest file not found when I dockerize the app while the PWA is installable when hosted on shinyapps.io?

Tags: shiny, dockerfile, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm working on deploying a computationally simple shinyMobile PWA (made in golem) as a docker container but am unable to get the local manifest file and service-worker to be located after turning it into a docker image and deploying it on Azure. I'm able to use a free version of Azure, so hopefully it's not an Azure-specific issue, but given the issues I've had with shinyapps.io, I imagine its not specific to Azure.

I used shinyMobile to create the app, set allowPWA = T under within the f7page and used charpente::set_pwa to generate the web.manifest and service-worker files. The instructions I was following had me put the files in the inst/app/www folder, however this never worked for me. What did work was copying the contents of the inst/app/www (i.e., icons folder with different sized icons inside, the favicon.ico, offline.html, service-worker.js, and manifest.webmanifest) into a new www folder in the project directory. Sometimes the css file doesn't load up right the first time, but after refreshing a few times it seems to work everytime thereafter, and the PWA is installable.

Here's a link to the working shinyapps.io PWA and a link to the github repo:

https://intralabcorp.shinyapps.io/RoloExample/

https://github.com/EwokOzwok/RoloExample/

Sidenote: please let me know if I'm missing something important with the CSS not loading properly until you refresh the page, at this point I'm chalking it up to issues with shinyapps.io having only one worker and low resources (free account) rather than some issue with the app itself.

My university's IT department is open to hosting the app on the main website if I can provide a working docker image, hence the effort to get the PWA features to work with the docker image.

What I've done to turn the shinyMobile app into a docker image after successfully deploying on shinyapps.io:

1. Deleted the rconnect folder from the golem package
2. Changed the start_url in the manifest.webmanifest from the shinyapps.io web address to the azurewebsite.net web address
3. Used the R-code 'golem::add_dockerfile_with_renv(output_dir = "deploy", document = T, port = 3838)' to create the docker file
4. Built the image successfully using the code provided by add_dockerfile_with_renv (works locally but cannot test PWA features locally)
5. Used a docker-slim workaround to minify the image (running ./minify.bash and including a text file pointing to additional r packages)

minify.bash contains:

```
    slim  build --target roloexample --show-clogs  --include-path-file 'r_path_includes.txt' --publish-port 3838 --http-probe=false
```

r_path_includes.txt contains:

```
    /.dockerenv
/libx32
/lib64
/lib32
/sbin
/usr/include/c++
/usr/local/lib/R/library/graphics
/usr/local/lib/R/library/man
/usr/local/lib/R/library/compiler
/usr/local/lib/R/library/methods
/usr/local/lib/R/library/stats
/usr/local/lib/R/library/datasets
/usr/local/lib/R/library/grDevices
/usr/local/lib/R/library/utils
/usr/local/lib/R/library/compiler
/usr/local/lib/R/library/tools
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library
/usr/local/lib/R/modules
```

6. Pushed the slim image to docker hub:
   https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/eeozmat/roloexample.slim/
7. Deployed the app on azure:
   https://roloexample.azurewebsites.net/

I've tried quite a few things to get it to work after looking up numerous similar questions online but nothing seems to help, so I'm writing this question hoping for some guidance!

These are the errors I can't seem to get past:

[image: Dev tools errors for Azure hosted docker container]

I've tried adding an extra tag in the header with crossorigin="use-credentials" after reading a few different folks who mentioned that this worked for them but ended up putting two instances referencing the manifest.webmanifest.
Ex:

```
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials>
```

I ended up seeing both in the header, but I still received the same error.

I have tried a few variations of this after reading more:

```
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials>
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials>
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials>
```

But the manifest.webmanifest file is still not able to be found and therefore the PWA is not installable.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!